# Implementing multiple nested functions

Tags: python, matplotlib, nested, ipython, fft

I have a interesting equation I want to defined that has a Fourier transform with two equations inside of it.

[image]

I'm not trying to solve for the differential equation, I can just represent as a normal function, L.

The other equations in this large equation are

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now as you can, these are some hefty functions to correlate. I'm not very experienced with nested functions and I don't know how to define what in order. When i say in order, i mean that the most efficient way possible that computer understands correctly.

I would think to start out by defining my first function, L, but i don't know what to implement first, my first function, the fourier transform, or the functions inside the fourier transform then the fourier transfrom.
Any similar examples and tips will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Edit: I'm not asking anybody to code it all for me, i just want to understand what will be more efficient. And yes there are values that have meaning, but you can treat them as constants.

Comment: Computer representation of differential equations depend on the method you use to solve them. For example, the representation of your equations are different using Euler methods and using Runge–Kutta methods. Sometimes it also depends of the way you solve the components, like using matrix inverse or Newton's method. One exercise is to code your own solver for 2D wave equation or heat equation. Then you will see what I mean

Comment: I stated that i'm not trying to solve the differential equations. For the purpose of this, i'm trying to graph a differential equation, so i'm treating these equations as regular functions, if that makes since. Data values will be implemented in these functions as well.

Comment: The representation depends on the preference of solver. You have to think about solving it to get a representation.

Comment: So i can't correlated all of these functions in a definition?

Comment: Define correlation. Plugging in?

Comment: Sorry. By correlation, i mean defining a function inside a defined function inside another defined function, so they all correlate with one another. I thing i might be using an incorrect word for it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to avoid computing sin(kR) multiple times (for a particular kR) ?

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with computer. You need to analytically arrange things, plugging in variables from one equation to another. Which equation absorbs all other equations is a choice you make based on need. Any one above can theoretically be the top-level equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally: Start with the innermost parts that doesn't actually need to call any custom functions anymore. Ideally test them by executing them with some mock data, to ensure they work as expected. Then move on to the functions that require only the functions that you already defined. Again, test run if possible. Rinse and repeat until you have defined the outermost function.

In your particular case, the three sub-equations are all independent, so you can implement them in any order (though I'd still start with whatever you feel is simplest). Then just plug them into the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 1):

Pardon me for not using Latex features. Let's say I have two equations

```
a/b = c
c+d = e
```

If you need to find `e`, you need to arrange equation 2 and plug it into equation 1

```
a/b = e-d
```

then rearrange

```
e = d + a/b
```

then define your function

```
def get_var_e(a, b, d):
   return d + a/b
```

Now if you need to get out `a`, the representation and choice of top-level equation will be completely different. You get the idea.